# a tag inside another tag html

Tags: javascript

```
.button1{


  background: #E68A00 url(wooden.jpg) repeat-x;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  height: 28px;
  width: 115px;
  margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
  padding: 0 0 0 7px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
  text-decoration:none;
  font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
  color : white;
  font-size: 30px;




  /*Rounded Corners*/
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;

/*Gradient*/
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

/*Transition*/
-webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
-moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
transition: All 0.5s ease;


}

pg.button1{ 
position:absolute;
right:0px;
top:100px;

}

pg:hover {
  width: 200px;
}






<pg <a class = "button1" href="http://www.google.com">Small $14 </a>  </pg>## Heading ##
```

The above tag was a link until i introduced the tag pg which is meant to position the link on the screen. The reason is that i still want to use the class with other objects ! so i don't have to duplicate my code! i have created tags like p1 p2 p3 p4 to use with that same class 
It actually positions it but its no longer a link ! Why is that ? and how do i get this working again ?

Comment: You're missing the `>` in the initial `<pg>` tag. That said, making up new tags is a pretty dubious practice.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than invent new tags, just use multiple classes. In this case, depending on what you're *actually* trying to do, you can do this:

```
<a class="button1 pg" href="...">Small $14</a>
```

Or this:

```
<div class="pg"><a class="button1" href="...">Small $14</a></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that actually fixed the link issue but the position has gone back to the top left corner, any idea on how to fix that ?

Comment: You probably need a containing element with `position:relative`