# How do you position CSS BUTTONS

Tags: html

```
    .button1{


      background: #E68A00 url(wooden.jpg) repeat-x;
      border: 2px solid #eee;
      height: 28px;
      width: 115px;
      margin: 50px 0 0 50px;
      padding: 0 0 0 7px;
      overflow: hidden;
      display: block;
      text-decoration:none;
      font-family: 'Sacramento', cursive;
      color : white;
      font-size: 30px;

      /*Rounded Corners*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;

    /*Gradient*/
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));

    /*Transition*/
    -webkit-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: All 0.5s ease;
    transition: All 0.5s ease;


    }

    #pg .button1{ 
    position: absolute
    left:340px;
    top:50px;

    }

    #p2 .button1{ 
    position:relative 
    left:340px;
    top:50px;

    }

    #p3 .button1{ 
    position:relative 
    left:40px;
    top:50px;

    }

    .button1:hover {
      width: 200px;
    }


 <a class="button1 pg " href="...">Small $14</a>
    <a class="button1 p2" href="...">Medium $15</a>
    <a class="button1 p2" href="...">Large $16</a>
```

I have posted This question more than twice today ! and still don't have a working solution The above code works but when i try changing the left and top values, nothing happens :( .
Basically i want change the position of 3 buttons sharing the same property(the design). Its so annoying, i have sat here for  the past 3 hours looking for a solution to this problem. please help !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to position Button sprites css](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465025/how-to-position-button-sprites-css). And the same code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15464726/a-tag-inside-another-tag-html

Answer (score 0):

You have no `id` attributes, yet you expect `#` ID selectors to work?

To select the first button, you would need something like `.button1.pg`